# FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'C:/.flutter_tool_state' (OS Error: Access is denied. , errno = 5)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was having some problems with Flutter so I decided to completely uninstall flutter and reinstall it from scratch. In the process of removing flutter, I uninstalled Android Studio, deleted the Android\sdk folder and also deleted the following files(don't remember file extensions):

**C:.flutter**

**C:.flutter_tool_state**

Now when I try to install flutter from scratch, any flutter command gives this error(flutter\bin is added in PATH). I have tried to manually make blank files of those names, that avoids this error but causes a crash after any flutter command.

Surprisingly, I tried looking for those 2 files on my other laptop which has flutter and android studio up and running and didn't find anything. Same result when I asked 2 of my friends to locate these files on their Laptops.

Here is the full error :

```
C:\Users\Sankhojyoti>flutter --version
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'C:/.flutter_tool_state' (OS Error: Access is denied.
, errno = 5)
#0      _File.throwIfError (dart:io/file_impl.dart:635:7)
#1      _File.openSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:479:5)
#2      _File.writeAsBytesSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:604:31)
#3      _File.writeAsStringSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:628:5)
#4      ForwardingFile.writeAsStringSync (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:154:16)
#5      ErrorHandlingFile.writeAsStringSync.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_file_system.dart:186:22)
#6      _runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_file_system.dart:351:14)
#7      ErrorHandlingFile.writeAsStringSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_file_system.dart:185:5)
#8      Config._flushValues (package:flutter_tools/src/base/config.dart:86:11)
#9      Config.setValue (package:flutter_tools/src/base/config.dart:75:5)
#10     _DefaultPersistentToolState.isRunningOnBot= (package:flutter_tools/src/persistent_tool_state.dart:120:45)
#11     BotDetector.isRunningOnBot (package:flutter_tools/src/base/bot_detector.dart:46:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     isRunningOnBot (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:107:48)
#13     runInContext.runnerWrapper (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:61:34)
#14     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:29)
#15     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
#16     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#17     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1630:10)
#18     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1550:10)
#19     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:18)
#20     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:65:24)
#21     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:52:10)
#22     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:73:9)
#23     main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/k/archive/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#24     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#25     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried changing your directory to `flutter\bin` folder and run `flutter --version` from there?

Comment: @Er1 I just tried, same error message. I tried it from flutter_console.bat, same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't copy .packages over from one machine to another. (It should be in .gitignore if using git.)

Also, remove the `pubspec.lock` file as well

Instead, run flutter packages get on the mac, and it will recreate .packages.

if the problem still exists then delete the android and ios folder from the project and recreate it using `flutter create .` (don't forget . here)

Comment: I am not talking about any app, so there's no worries about copying from another machine. the default counter app of flutter doesn't run either.
and I'm working on Windows.
flutter create . gave the same error. it seems to be that file is what's missing

Comment: open cmd as administrator and then try `flutter create app_name`.

Comment: Thanks man, doing this got those files back in my C drive. this issue is solved for me

Comment: can you tell me how did you solved this issue

Comment: which OS are you using? @ArnabBhattacharya

Answer (score 0):

This was worked for me :

open cmd as administrator and then try `flutter create app_name`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the directory from the existing directory, this works for me.